# Dynamically set a property in an Item Template

Tags: wpf, datagrid, listcollectionview

I set an image path of an Image in a StackPanel used in a GroupItem using the following resource (which as is works fine):

```
<Style x:Key="GroupHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                <Expander Name="expander" IsExpanded="True" >
                    <Expander.Header>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Image Source="pack://application:,,,/Resources/History.ico" Margin="2,0"  
                                   Width="18" Height="18" ></Image>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Padding="2,0"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Expander.Header>
                    <ItemsPresenter />
                </Expander>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Which is used in this DataGrid:

```
    <DataGrid Name="JobHistory" CanUserAddRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ColumnWidth="*"
              CanUserDeleteRows="False" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Grid.Row="2" 
              Grid.ColumnSpan="5" CanUserResizeRows="False" 
              Grid.RowSpan="2" IsTextSearchEnabled="True" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"  >
        <DataGrid.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle ContainerStyle="{StaticResource GroupHeaderStyle}">
                <GroupStyle.Panel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <DataGridRowsPresenter/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </GroupStyle.Panel>
            </GroupStyle>
        </DataGrid.GroupStyle>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Status" Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="True">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Image Source="{Binding ResultImagePath}" Height="18" Width="18"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Job description" Binding="{Binding JobDescription}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

The DataView is grouped via this code:

```
    ListCollectionView collection = new ListCollectionView(JobData);
    collection.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("Name"));
    JobHistory.ItemsSource = collection;
```

My Question: How can I dynamically set  the image Source in the StackPanel?

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
  <Image Source="pack://application:,,,/Resources/History.ico" Margin="2,0"  
     Width="18" Height="18" ></Image>
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Padding="2,0"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Edit 1:
Using:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
            <Image x:Key="image" Source="pack://application:,,,/Resources/History.ico" Height="18" Width="18" Margin="2,0"/>
</UserControl.Resources>


<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource ResourceKey=image}"/>
      Width="18" Height="18" ></Image>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Padding="2,0"/>
</StackPanel>
```

as  user2760623 suggested works.

My Problem however remains. At any given time I have multiple rows grouped by "Name".  There can also be several different Groups.  Depending on the Jobs current Status, I would like to Change the Image in the GroupItem Header. So how do I figure out which header is the "right" Header, and how do I manipulate exactly that one single Header?

Answer (score 1):

Put  the image source as a dynamic resource, and then you can change it. Just do the following:

1. Define the namespace - `xmlns:clr="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"`.
2. Add as resource - `<clr:String x:Key="imageSource" >the path...</clr:String>`.
3. And the image itself - `<Image Source="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=imageSource}"`.
4. And when you want to change it - `this.Resources["imageSource"] = "another path..."`.

You can also do the same concept just put the whole image as a resource (instead of just the image path), than you don't need to add the namespace (number 1 above). And put it as a Content of a ContentControl - 
`<ContentControl Content="{StaticResource ResourceKey=image}"/>`.

Comment: I'm getting an error.  I added `xmlns:clr="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"` to my `<UserControl x:Class...>` and added `<clr:String x:Key="imageSource">pack://application:,,,/Resources/History.ico</clr:String>` to  `<UserControl.Resources>`.  Then set `<Image Source="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=imageSource}" Margin="2,0"`.  Now I receive error 51 -  **An object of the type "System.String" cannot be applied to a property that expects the type "System.Windows.Media.ImageSource"**.  Any Ideas?

Comment: My mistake. I guess you can't just put a string resource as a ImageSource. Anyway you can use the other option I mentioned - putting the whole image as a resource.

Comment: As I wrote, put the (resource which is an) image as a the content of a ContentControl.

Comment: No. That's not working either. `<Image> <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource ResourceKey=image}"/> </Image>` results in the following Errors: **The type 'Image' does not support direct Content** and **Cannot add content to an object of type "Image"**

Comment: I ment just the ContentControl, without the <Image> tag surrounding it.

Comment: Please see Edit 1.  +1 for your help.

Comment: How do you determine which image is suppose to be shown?   BTW, maybe you should post it as another question, because I son't know how many people are going to see this one.

Comment: [New Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19209962/access-objects-dynamically-set-created-by-templates)